# Entity Framework Core - trying to create a database from a migration but getting an issue with "Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting services"

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

As you do I googled this and did not get much in the way of targeted results.

I have updated my project to .NET Core 5 and in particular using SDK 5.0.100-preview.8.20417.9 with the latest preview of Visual Studio 2019.

The SDK is `5.0.100-preview.8.20417.9` [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk].

I ran a migration using:

```
dotnet ef migrations add INITIAL --context CATALOGContext -s ../Jobsledger.API
```

and got the following error:

> An error occurred while accessing the Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting services. Continuing without the application service provider.
>
> Error: Method not found: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationBuilder Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationBuilder.AddScheme(System.String, System.String, System.Action`2<System.__Canon,!!2>)'.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60561851/an-error-occurred-while-accessing-the-microsoft-extensions-hosting-services-when) on Stackoverflow and also [this](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/pull/24600)

That second one indicates they have deprecated some of what was once there.

I had this working in an earlier version of my program and I also included `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory` in a migrations file in the startup and that did work before.

Can someone point me in the right direction with this. The error (for me) is cryptic and when I look closely at what that second option indicates it tells me they pulled out code that I needed.. however I am lost on this..

Comment: When did it stop working?   What version of SDK were you using before upgrade. It looks like it is an authentication issue.  Five years ago the industry obsoleted TLS 1.0/1.1 which is used for authentication due to encryption had security flaws.  Microsfot in June pushed a Security updated to windows which disabled TLS 1.0/1.1 on servers and require the use of TLS 1.2.  One possibility for this error is your client is still using TLS 1.0/1.1, I do not have enough info to be positive.

Answer (score 0):

Please try "Consolidate" from NuGet in Manage Nuget Packages, I had the same issue and solved it when versions were different between projects. If not, please give us the PM console message with the berbose option