# How to generate migrations in a .NET worker service for .net 6

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I'm trying to add a migration via `Add-Migration {Name}` or `dotnet ef migrations add {Name}` with a .NET 6 Worker Service. It build successfully and I can see from the migration logs its trying to but just dies silently at

> Using application service provider from Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.

Here's the full stack log once it finishes building

```
dotnet exec --depsfile C:\Users\me\source\repos\SmartSafeFinancials\src\StoresDaysheetProcessor.Worker\bin\Debug\net6.0\StoresDaysheetProcessor.Worker.deps.json --additionalprobingpath C:\Users\me\.nuget\packages --runtimeconfig C:\Users\me\source\repos\SmartSafeFinancials\src\StoresDaysheetProcessor.Worker\bin\Debug\net6.0\StoresDaysheetProcessor.Worker.runtimeconfig.json C:\Users\me\.dotnet\tools\.store\dotnet-ef\6.0.2\dotnet-ef\6.0.2\tools\netcoreapp3.1\any\tools\netcoreapp2.0\any\ef.dll migrations add Initialcreate -o ./Data/SmartSafeFinancials/Migrations --context SmartSafeFinancialsDbContext --assembly C:\Users\me\source\repos\SmartSafeFinancials\src\StoresDaysheetProcessor.Worker\bin\Debug\net6.0\StoresDaysheetProcessor.Worker.dll --project C:\Users\me\source\repos\SmartSafeFinancials\src\StoresDaysheetProcessor.Worker\StoresDaysheetProcessor.Worker.csproj --startup-assembly C:\Users\me\source\repos\SmartSafeFinancials\src\StoresDaysheetProcessor.Worker\bin\Debug\net6.0\StoresDaysheetProcessor.Worker.dll --startup-project C:\Users\me\source\repos\SmartSafeFinancials\src\StoresDaysheetProcessor.Worker\StoresDaysheetProcessor.Worker.csproj --project-dir C:\Users\me\source\repos\SmartSafeFinancials\src\StoresDaysheetProcessor.Worker\ --root-namespace StoresDaysheetProcessor.Worker --language C# --framework net6.0 --nullable --working-dir C:\Users\me\source\repos\SmartSafeFinancials\src\StoresDaysheetProcessor.Worker --verbose
Using assembly 'StoresDaysheetProcessor.Worker'.
Using startup assembly 'StoresDaysheetProcessor.Worker'.
Using application base 'C:\Users\me\source\repos\SmartSafeFinancials\src\StoresDaysheetProcessor.Worker\bin\Debug\net6.0'.
Using working directory 'C:\Users\me\source\repos\SmartSafeFinancials\src\StoresDaysheetProcessor.Worker'.
Using root namespace 'StoresDaysheetProcessor.Worker'.
Using project directory 'C:\Users\me\source\repos\SmartSafeFinancials\src\StoresDaysheetProcessor.Worker\'.
Remaining arguments: .
Finding DbContext classes...
Finding IDesignTimeDbContextFactory implementations...
Finding application service provider in assembly 'StoresDaysheetProcessor.Worker'...
Finding Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting service provider...
Using environment 'Development'.
Using application service provider from Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.
```

Database context

```
public class SmartSafeFinancialsDbContext : DbContext
{
    public SmartSafeFinancialsDbContext(DbContextOptions<SmartSafeFinancialsDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<StoreDaysheetDay> StoreDaysheetDays { get; set; } = null!;

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
    }
}
```

Program.cs

```
    var builder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureServices((builder, services) =>
        {
            services.AddDbContextFactory<SmartSafeFinancialsDbContext>(options =>
            {
             
   options.UseSqlServer(_configuration.GetConnectionString("SmartSafeFinancials"));
            });
        });

    var host = builder.Build();
    await host.RunAsync();
```

Comment: See following : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60561851/an-error-occurred-while-accessing-the-microsoft-extensions-hosting-services-when?force_isolation=true

Comment: I saw this, but unfortunately it didn't work by just adding a `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory` directly to my worker service. Confusingly, I'm getting no errors unlike that OP.

Comment: Did it complete?  Did you try running code?  Did you check Event Veiwer for errors?

Comment: No - as stated in the question it gets to `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting` and exits silently. No Event Viewer logs. Not sure what you mean by "try running code". The code works as far as production code is concerned.

Comment: Maybe it exit because it finished successfully.

Comment: Unfortuantely, it's not. A normal migration log acquires a DbContext and generates a migration - which is all displayed in the verbose logging.

Comment: Did you see this link on above page : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dbcontext-creation?tabs=dotnet-core-cli&force_isolation=true

Comment: As stated in my first comment, adding a IDesignTimeDbContextFactory to my worker service for my DbContext invokes _no change to this non-working behavior_.

Comment: Is the connection completing?  What changed between working and non working conditions beside the Net version?  Did you check log files in database for errors?  Did you download latest runtime version of Core on deploy machine (or are you running on same machine as build)?

Comment: This is to generate a migration. What does the database connection have to do with the differences between the Modelsnapshot and the model itself? I’m not trying to apply a migration I’m trying to add one to be applied later.

Comment: You are using Entity where there is a mapping file that associates the DataBase Tables to the c# classes which needs updating and you need to connect to the server to be able to do the updating.

Comment: Yes, but I don’t need the database connection until after this step. Separately, and at a later date. There is no database connection to generate a migration.

Comment: The migration isn't completing probably because the  connection cannot be made.  You can't have your cake and pie too!

Comment: Thanks for trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up having to create a separate project and then using the normal `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<>`. Not ideal since I didn't want the bloat of a second project but that allowed me to get through the command line to add migrations to later be applied.