# How to resolve Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting services error?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I try to add migration in my EF Core 5 project. All entities are set up well. Unfortunately when I do `add-migration InitialMigration` then the following error occurs:

> An error occurred while accessing the Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting
> services. Continuing without the application service provider. Error:
> Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating
> the service descriptor 'ServiceType:
> MediatR.IRequestHandler`2[TicketManagement.Application.Features.Events.Commands.CreateEvent.CreateEventCommand,System.Guid]
> Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType:
> TicketManagement.Application.Features.Events.Commands.CreateEvent.CreateEventCommandHandler':
> Unable to resolve service for type
> 'TicketManagement.Application.Models.Mail.EmailSettings' while
> attempting to activate
> 'TicketManagement.Infrastructure.Mail.EmailService'.) (Error while
> validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType:
> TicketManagement.Application.Contracts.Infrastructure.IEmailService
> Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType:
> TicketManagement.Infrastructure.Mail.EmailService': Unable to resolve
> service for type
> 'TicketManagement.Application.Models.Mail.EmailSettings' while
> attempting to activate
> 'TicketManagement.Infrastructure.Mail.EmailService'.)

I added all services to `Startup.cs` class.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
  {
     services.AddApplicationServices();
     services.AddPersistenceServices(Configuration);
     services.AddInfrastructureServices(Configuration);
     services.AddControllers();

     services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
         {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "TicketManagement.Api", Version = "v1" });
      });

     services.AddCors(options =>
          {
             options.AddPolicy("Open", builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod());
          });
}
```

WHat's the root cause of this kind of error?

Comment: And where `EmailSettings` are registered?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [An error occurred while accessing the Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting services when do first migrations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60561851/an-error-occurred-while-accessing-the-microsoft-extensions-hosting-services-when)

Comment: Guys, I didn't retrieve configured options from `EmailSettings`, that was a problem. Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `EmailSettings` to the service collection as `EmailService` does not know how to resolve the service.

Comment: I added it to service collection: `services.Configure<EmailSettings>(configuration.GetSection("EmailSettings"));` , `services.AddTransient<IEmailService, EmailService>();`. The issue was I forgot to retrieve configured EmailSettings instances using IOptions interface. Now it's ok. Thanks for your hints, it helped a lot.